# AForge GetObjectsRectangles() gives false output

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

For me the Aforge rectangle detection gives completely false coordinates.

Here's my code:

```
public List<System.Drawing.Rectangle> Detect(string path)
{
    var image = GetImage(path);
    var blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
    blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
    blobCounter.MinWidth = 50;
    blobCounter.MinHeight = 50;
    blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);
    var rects = blobCounter.GetObjectsRectangles();
    return rects.ToList();
}

public System.Drawing.Bitmap GetImage(string path)
{
    BitmapSource bSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
    var image = Helpers.BitmapConverter.GetBitmap(bSource);
    return image;
}
```

and my test image is this:

[image]

I've also tried reverting the colors, but nothing seems to help.
I always get just: `{X = 16 Y = 42 Width = 51 Height = 141}`  That is obviously wrong for that rectangle in the image. How do I use Aforge to detect rectangles?

Comment: Are you using Andrew Kirillow's original *AForge.NET Framework* from NuGet or Google Code? Is `Helpers.BitmapConverter.GetBitmap` a "home brewed" method? In that case, please include its relevant parts in the question text. I have ran your code, but replaced the code in `GetImage` with `return new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(path));`. With this change, `X = 64` and `Width = 203`, i.e. 4 times your result. Could it be that your helper method is handling bytes per pixel incorrectly?

Comment: Actually, my image was in wrong 8-bit format, it seems that it needs to be 32-bit. And the background needs to be black. :)

Answer (score 1):

By using the AForge `BlobCounter` class `GetObjectsInformation` method.

Using the image provided, a snippet of the code provided in a simple Windows Forms Application with a picture box and a button I was able to detect the rectangle by drawing a lime green line over the original image using the following code.

```
            //after pictureBox1's image has been set to the provided image.

            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
            blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
            blobCounter.MinWidth = 50;
            blobCounter.MinHeight = 50;
            blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);

            Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

            Blob blob = blobs[0];

            SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Lime, 2);

            List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);

            List<IntPoint> corners;

            if (shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon(edgePoints, out corners))
            {
                PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners);

                Pen pen;

                if (subType == PolygonSubType.Unknown)
                {
                    pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? redPen : redPen;
                }
                else
                {
                    pen = greenPen;
                }

                System.Drawing.Point[] array = new System.Drawing.Point[corners.Count];

                for (int i = 0, n = corners.Count; i < n; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = new System.Drawing.Point(corners[i].X + 1, corners[i].Y + 1);
                }

                g.DrawPolygon(pen, array);
            }

            redPen.Dispose();
            greenPen.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();

            pictureBox1.Image = image;
            pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
            pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
```

Provided Image

[image: Provided Image]

Processed Image

[image]